# Re-Parenting of Owned Children

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0, value-objects

I have a problem with re-parenting owned children. My model is as follows:

- Shift owns an Itinerary
- Itinerary owns many Waypoints
- Waypoint owns many Assignments

```
public class Shift
{
    public Guid Id { get; }        
    public Itinerary Itinerary { get; private set; }

    // Constructors 

    public void AddWaypoint(Waypoint waypoint)
    {
        Itinerary = Itinerary.AddWaypoint(waypoint);
    }
}

public class Itinerary
{
    public IReadOnlyList<Waypoint> Waypoints { get; }

    // Constructors

    public Itinerary AddWaypoint(Waypoint waypoint)
    {
        var newWaypoints = Waypoints.Append(waypoint).ToList();

        return new Itinerary(ItineraryName, newWaypoints);
    }
}
```

The catch is, that Itinerary, Waypoints and Assignments are implemented as ValueObjects, which don't have a corresponding foreign key prop and also don't allow for mutating methods. So, I configured EF to use shadow props. The configuration code is:

```
routeBuilder.Entity<Shift>()
                .ToTable("Shifts");
            routeBuilder.Entity<Shift>()
                .HasKey(p => p.Id);
            routeBuilder.Entity<Shift>()
                .Property(p => p.Id)
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            routeBuilder.Entity<Shift>()
                .OwnsOne<Itinerary>(r => r.Itinerary, itineraryBuilder =>
                {
                    itineraryBuilder.ToTable("Itineraries");

                    itineraryBuilder.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                    itineraryBuilder.HasKey("Id", "ShiftId");
                    
                    itineraryBuilder.Property(i => i.ItineraryName);
                    
                    itineraryBuilder.OwnsMany<Waypoint>(p => p.Waypoints, waypointBuilder =>
                    {
                        waypointBuilder.ToTable("Waypoints");
                        waypointBuilder.WithOwner()
                            .HasPrincipalKey("Id")
                            .HasForeignKey("ItineraryId");

                        waypointBuilder.Property<Guid>("Id")
                            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                        waypointBuilder.HasKey("Id");

                        waypointBuilder.OwnsMany<Assignment>(w => w.Assignments, assignmentBuilder =>
                        {
                            assignmentBuilder.ToTable("Assignments");
                            assignmentBuilder.WithOwner()
                                .HasForeignKey("WaypointId");

                            assignmentBuilder.Property<Guid>("Id")
                                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                            assignmentBuilder.HasKey("Id");

                            assignmentBuilder.Property(a => a.Name);
                        });
                    });
                });
```

My test code, which does not work because the first waypoint always gets deleted, is

```
using var db = new AppContext()

db.ChangeTracker.DeleteOrphansTiming = CascadeTiming.OnSaveChanges;

var shift = new Shift("s1");
var waypoint = new Waypoint("w1");
shift.AddWaypoint(waypoint);
                
db.Shifts.Add(shift);
                
db.SaveChanges();
                
var retrievedRoute = db.Shifts.First();
retrievedRoute.AddWaypoint(new Waypoint("w3", new List<Assignment>()));
               
db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
Console.WriteLine(db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem seems to be with the re-parenting part  `Itinerary = Itinerary.AddWaypoint(waypoint);`. The output of the change tracker is given below. FKs seem to be correctly set, however, the entity state is not, and so the first waypoint is deleted from the DB. I already tried setting the DeleteOrphansTiming, but without success.

```
Itinerary {Id: af50adfb-87f1-4311-b2b0-8c447dea2ed5, ShiftId: 65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997} Added
  Id: 'af50adfb-87f1-4311-b2b0-8c447dea2ed5' PK
  ShiftId: '65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997' PK FK
  ItineraryName: 'i-s1'
  Waypoints: [{Id: 49ad3b5b-d1f9-4973-8a2d-4bfce995732f}, {Id: 6db0e434-6e6d-47ad-8fe4-26d2ce755427}]
Itinerary {Id: eee6762a-0d10-457d-9242-67e5a67c6872, ShiftId: 65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997} Deleted
  Id: 'eee6762a-0d10-457d-9242-67e5a67c6872' PK
  ShiftId: '65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997' PK FK
  ItineraryName: 'i-s1'
  Waypoints: [{Id: 49ad3b5b-d1f9-4973-8a2d-4bfce995732f}]
Shift {Id: 65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997} Unchanged
  Id: '65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997' PK
  ParentProp: 's1'
  Itinerary: {Id: af50adfb-87f1-4311-b2b0-8c447dea2ed5, ShiftId: 65ae52c7-9b30-4629-9f50-938423642997}
Waypoint {Id: 49ad3b5b-d1f9-4973-8a2d-4bfce995732f} Deleted
  Id: '49ad3b5b-d1f9-4973-8a2d-4bfce995732f' PK
  DependantProp: 'w1'
  ItineraryId: 'af50adfb-87f1-4311-b2b0-8c447dea2ed5' FK Originally 'eee6762a-0d10-457d-9242-67e5a67c6872'
  Assignments: []
Waypoint {Id: 6db0e434-6e6d-47ad-8fe4-26d2ce755427} Added
  Id: '6db0e434-6e6d-47ad-8fe4-26d2ce755427' PK
  DependantProp: 'w3'
  ItineraryId: 'af50adfb-87f1-4311-b2b0-8c447dea2ed5' FK
  Assignments: []
```

Workarounds I identified are:

- Allow for mutating methods within the ValueObjects
- Re-Initializing existing waypoints in `itinerary.AddWaypoint(Waypoint wp)`. However, this would delete all waypoints from the DB and insert them again, since the IDs changed.

Does anyone has a solution for this issue? :)

Best regards,
DS

Comment: EF Core owned entity types are *not* value objects. EF Core (at least currently) has no notion of "value object". And owned entity type is still "entity type", hence is identified by both key and reference (like "regular" entity type).

Comment: @IvanStoev I configured the PKs of the owned Waypoints to be an auto-generated Id column. The tables are set up correctly. The ChangeTracker also seems to pick that up. Since the FK is therefore not part of the PK, I thought I could re-parent the waypoints to the new Itinerary. Do you have another approach to configure EF Core to pick up the mentioned VOs in my domain?